# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC returning AmbiguousMatchException, server error 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and areas.

This problem occurs in development using IIS Express, I haven't even got it to the point I can deploy to a live (IIS) server yet. The server is throwing an error 500 at the end of the startup process.

Exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
>
> Matches:
>
> FleetLogix.Intranet.Areas.Maps.Controllers.HomeController.Index (FleetLogix.Intranet)
> FleetLogix.Intranet.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController.Index (FleetLogix.Intranet)
> FleetLogix.Intranet.Controllers.HomeController.Index (FleetLogix.Intranet)
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This is my routing:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "AdminArea",
        areaName: "Admin",
        pattern: "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "AnchorArea",
        areaName: "Anchor",
        pattern: "Anchor/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "DashboardArea",
        areaName: "Dashboard",
        pattern: "Dashboard/{controller=DriverBehaviour}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "MapsArea",
        areaName: "Maps",
        pattern: "Maps/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "ReportGroupsArea",
        areaName: "ReportGroups",
        pattern: "ReportGroups/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "MaintenanceArea",
        areaName: "Maintenance",
        pattern: "Maintenance/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I'm not doing anything special. I've seen fixes that say to add an attribute to the methods eg:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
```

but this is complaining about base index methods that have the same profile. The path to them is what's meant to differentiate.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path "`/`" or "`/Home/Index`" request matched multiple endpoints. You could add area attribute to separate. All tested and worked.

1. Add `[Area("Admin")]` to `/Area/Admin/HomeController`:

   ```
     [Area("Admin")]
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
          public IActionResult Index()
          {
              return View();
          }
     }
   ```
2. Add  `[Area("Maps")]` to `/Area/Maps/HomeController`

   ```
    [Area("Maps")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
   ```

Now you have these mappings:

- `localhost:44388/admin` => /Area/Admin/HomeController/Index Action
- `localhost:44388/maps` => /Area/Maps/HomeController/Index Action
- `localhost:44388/` => /HomeController/Index Action

Comment: Away from my desk, but I know that [Area(xyz)]is specified On most controllers.  I’ll check when I’m back from lunch

Comment: :) Ok, if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Most did have the attribute, AdminController did not.  Have added it, as well as valid [Authorize(Policy = "Requirexyz")] where that was missing too.  I have issues still, but they're different issues worthy of a new question.  TYVM for your help.:)